# Construct Algebraically closed field that contains the prime field F

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Please give me some hint or reference to a book to solve the following problem. I have been looking concepts in Abstract algebra by Dummit and foote, but could not able to find some specific approach to solve the problem:

Construct an algebraically closed field that contains the prime field $$F_p$$

Comment: Theorem 1.2.1 in http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9103.pdf does this.

Comment: @Dave, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Dave, I have gone through the reference you provided and find it a bit advanced to understand. Could you please provide some other detailed reference?

Comment: I would just try googling "algebraic closure of finite field", which is what I did.

Comment: @Dave, thank you :)